# Angular - Loop check if value exist inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

I need help to check if a value exists in the object.

**My Object = (vagas.etapas)**

```
"Etapas" : {
  "05daf060-87cb-47cf-8c98-65b36941613d" : "Name 1",
  "0bf7aabf-42df-4f7d-86dc-af81e6cef394" : "Name 2",
  "13f8ebda-2b0b-4868-b856-1c88b405d853" : "Name 3",
  "25b9370e-8bf3-464f-ae7c-e72937d2c490" : "Name 4",
  "5a1dfca0-d0b0-4cf7-bc34-12050bafc495" : "Name 5"
},
```

Ex: check if **"Name 3"** exists in the array

The properties are random and I cannot do it like this:

```
for (let e of Object.keys(vaga.Etapas)) {
  if (vaga.Etapas[e].hasOwnProperty("13f8ebda-2b0b-4868-b856-1c88b405d853")) {
  // do something
}
```

How do I achieve this in a for ... loop?

Comment: Do you want to check ```value``` or ```key``` in an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
const objToFind = "Name 3";

if (Object.values(etapas).indexOf(objToFind >= 0)) {
   console.log('Value present');
} else {
   // not found
}
```

Comment: I use (Object.values(vaga.Etapas[e]).includes(nameToFind) instead .indexOf